# I am writing my first discord bot and creating roles with limitations is weird

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to allow users to add a role based on what they type in, but it only works if what they typed in is the same as something in an array. Here is the code currently:

```html
    let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID)
    let user = receivedMessage.author.username
    let fullCommand = receivedMessage.content.substr(0) // Remove the leading exclamation mark
    let splitCommand = fullCommand.split(" ") // Split the message up in to pieces for each space
    let role = splitCommand.slice(1).toString()
      let timezones = ['utc', 'utc-1', 'utc-2', 'utc-3', 'utc-4', 'utc-5', 'utc-6', 'utc-7', 'utc-8',                            'utc-9', 'utc-10', 'utc-11', 'utc+1', 'utc+2', 'utc+3', 'utc+4', 'utc+5', 'utc+6', 
                       'utc+7', 'utc+8', 'utc+9', 'utc+10', 'utc+11'] 
    let word = "hi"
    for (let i = 0; i < timezones.length; i++) {
      word = timezones[i].toString()
      if (role == word) {
        receivedMessage.guild.roles.create({
           data: {
           name: role,
           color: 'RED'
           }
        })
        console.log(user + " added " + role + " as their role")
      }
    }
  }
```

There is probably something simple wrong with it that I am not noticing. It stopped adding when I added the for loop though, if that helps at all. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I did something silly and just removed the permissions tag in the role. I can't believe didn't do that earlier lol